# Is it possible to use CamelCase class names in Magento models?

Tags: magento

Let's say you have a class name `Space_Module_Model_LongModelName` and you want to reference it as:

```
Mage::getModel('module/longmodelname');
```

This seems to work in some development environments, but doesn't seem to work in all environments.  Probably has to do with a file system case sensitivity setting.

The error that you get in environments where it doesn't work is that the `include()` for `Space/Module/Model/Longmodelname.php` failed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a config-node in your config.xml called  global/models/yourpackage in which you save your Prefix for your class models.

When you call Mage::getModel('packagename/classname') Magento fetches this config node e.g. Company_Yourmodule_Models adds a _ and then the classname with uppercase first letter:

Company_Yourmodule_Models_Classname

if you have cAMElcaSe classnames, it is the same way. So let's say your class' name is ClassName then you have to call Mage::getModel('packagename/className') and magento resolves it to: Company_Yourmodule_Models_ClassName

Comment: Hi Schrank. Welcome @StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` specifically `getGroupedClassName();` as you'll notice `uc_words` is used in the method when building the `$className`, which will capitalize every other word in the class name string.

So your class name of `LongModelName` will become `Longmodelname` for the include.

You could easily extend this to work the way you want but since its such a main piece of Magento's factory generation personally I would not touch it in fear of breaking other 3rd party modules, and live with the non-camel case namespace.

The reason ImportExport works is because it is the module name and not a class name.  I've run into the same issue before and as annoying as it is I tend to just keep class names non-Camel cased.

Comment: Thanks Boomer.  I think that uc_words() actually uppercases the first letter but doesn't forcefully lower case the rest of the letters.  So I think that Fabian's suggestion of camel-casing the class alias does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

For sure there is possibility to use camelcase - you can see module e.g. ImportExport in Magento core. I think all is about setting correct (with camel cases) names in xmls

Comment: Thanks Jerzy, but I think you're referring to camel case module names and not *model* names, they different issues - but both are possible now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, another note:

If you want to use camelCased classnames in addition to filenames, make sure the following part of your *{moduleName}/etc/config.xml* is camelCased as well:

```xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <ProbablyYourCompanyOrModuleName>
            <ModuleName_resource>
                <entities>
                    <!-- "longModelName" below should be CamelCased, but prob the first letter will be lowercased -->
                    <longModelName>
                        <table>your_db_table_name</table>
                    </longModelName>
                </entities>
            </ModuleName_resource>
        </ProbablyYourCompanyOrModuleName>
    </models>
</global>
```

```

The  portion should be camelCased with the first letter lowercased. Otherwise, you'll get an exception of `Can't retrieve entity config: yourmodule/longModelName`

(see `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getTableName()`)